# FCM too_many_registration problem is showing in real device but not in emulator?

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

```
  void signWithGoogle(
    BuildContext context,
    WidgetRef? ref,
  ) async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount =
          await googleSignIn.signIn();

      String? deviceToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();

      UserModel.User user = UserModel.User(
        id: '',
        uniqueId: '',
        displayName: googleSignInAccount!.displayName!.toString(),
        email: googleSignInAccount.email,
        mobile: 0,
        profilePicture: googleSignInAccount.photoUrl != ''
            ? googleSignInAccount.photoUrl
            : profilePic,
        followers: [],
        following: [],
        token: '',
        deviceToken: deviceToken!,
        createdAt: '',
      );

      http.Response res = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('$url/api/signup'),
        body: user.toJson(),
        headers: <String, String>{
          "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        },
      );

      if (context.mounted) {
        httpErrorHanding(
          res: res,
          context: context,
          onSuccess: () async {
            SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
            await prefs.setString(
                'x-access-token', jsonDecode(res.body)['token']);
            ref!.read(userProvider.notifier).updateUser(res.body);
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => BottomBar(data: 0),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      showSnackbar(context, e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

This is my registration code and when I am trying to store the FCM token in the emulator it works properly but on my real device it shows the error:
"Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure exceptions: TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS. Won't retry the operation. in real device"

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: It is not working on my device but working properly on other devices.